# Partial update REST in Spring Boot and Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a project with Spring Boot + Kotlin + Morphia.

I need add partial update of my entities. My actual post method:

```
   @PostMapping("update/")
    fun updateStudent(@RequestBody @Valid  student: Student, results: BindingResult): ResponseData<Student> {

        if (results.hasErrors())
            return ResponseData(errors = results.errors)


        if (!student.canEdit(login.user))
            return ResponseData()


        student.save()
        return ResponseData(data = student)
    }
```

I need read student from database and update only the sended fields

Comment: Should be PATCH not POST. How to distinguish set a student property to NULL? I would say it's better to have a map of request parameters. Read Student from DB (e.g. by id) and then go through the map updating appropriate field of Student. Finally save the Student back to DB.

Comment: All my fields are "no nullable", so, I don't have any null.

I read about "ModelAttribute" that load first the element from DB and after apply the data from request, but I don't know how start with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl
import java.util.HashSet

fun getNullPropertyNames(source: Any): Array<String> {
    val src = BeanWrapperImpl(source)
    val pds = src.propertyDescriptors
    val emptyNames = HashSet<String>()
    for (pd in pds) {
        if (src.getPropertyValue(pd.name) == null) emptyNames.add(pd.name)
    }
    return emptyNames.toTypedArray()
}
```

And in controller

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils

@RestController
class GateController {

    @Autowired
    private val modelRepository: MyRepository? = null

    // allow both 'full' and 'partial' update
    @PutMapping("/somemodel/{Id}")
    fun updateModel(
            @PathVariable Id: Long,
            @RequestBody requestBody: SomeModel
    ): SomeModel {
        var objFromDb = modelRepository!!.findById(Id).orElseThrow { ResourceNotFoundException("Object not found with id: " + Id) }
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(requestBody, objFromDb, *getNullPropertyNames(requestBody))
        return modelRepository.save(objFromDb)
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to implement. Reading Student from DB and copying properties from the student from request.

I post java code but it's no problem to convert to kotlin

```
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
db = new Mongo();
Datastore ds = morphia.createDatastore(db, appname, user, pass.toCharArray());

morphia.map(Student.class);
Student existing= ds.find(Student.class).field("id").equal(student.id).get();
```

Then you can use Apache BeanUtils

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29

```
 BeanUtils.copyProperties(existing, student);
```

then

```
existing.save();
```

Comment: The problem is that all my variables are "no nullable", so, BeanUtils replace all data by "default data"

Comment: It's rather business logic problem. How to skip empty (default values) fields? Try to explain how you would do it manually. That's why I suggested initially a Map with key value. If something is not sent you don't override existing value.